# Is it possible to display text in multiple languages in a mobile app?

Tags: localization, internationalization, mobile-application

Let's consider an example:

I am using Yelp's mobile app. The app is currently installed in English on my phone. All reviews available for a particular restaurant on the mobile app are in English. However, on the Yelp website, there are a few reviews for the same restaurant in Spanish and French.

My question: Is it possible to display reviews in multiple languages in the mobile app using 'localization' concepts?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible, I think what Yelp is trying to do is be helpful and only show you reviews in English (that they think you can read).

If Yelp asks for location, they can grab your location and cross reference it with the most popular languages in your area, then only show the reviews of those languages.